# Create a .dot graph of a C++ projects dependencies from the output of gcc -MG -MM

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, g++, graphviz

I'm trying to visualize the dependencies of a c++ project. I'd like to use standard tools: g++ to generate the dependencies, sed(?) to format, and graphviz/dot to and output a svg.

I'm invoking g++ with `g++ -MG -MM *.cc`. The output looks something like:

```
compare.o: compare.cc compare.h types.h
config.o: config.cc config.h mute.h types.h log.h
lamp.o: lamp.cc lamp.h il_types.h
log.o: log.cc log.h FreeRTOS.h task.h mute.h string.h
login.o: login.cc login.h \
 utils/bcrypt.hpp utils/async.h
math.o: math.cc math.h types.h log.h FreeRTOS.h task.h \
  mute.h
```

How can I convert this output to dot graph syntax, so I can visualize the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could easily use `awk` or the like to generate a .dot file from that, but since you're already using C++, might as well just use it for the task too (I do this sort of thing a lot in C and C++ code to generate dot representations of data structures for easy viewing. It's not really that different getting input from a stream instead of walking a data structure).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

// Read a complete line where a trailing \ indicates a continued line
bool readline(std::istream &in, std::string &line) {
  if (std::getline(in, line)) {
    while (line.back() == '\\') {
      std::string continuation;
      if (!std::getline(in, continuation)) {
        std::cerr << "Missing continuation line!\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      line.replace(line.end() - 1, line.end(), continuation);
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Replace (some) characters that can't be in dot node names with underscores
std::string normalize(const std::string &name) {
  std::string norm;
  norm.reserve(name.size());
  std::replace_copy_if(name.begin(), name.end(), std::back_inserter(norm),
                       [](char c){ return std::strchr("/. ", c) != nullptr; },
                       '_');
  return norm;
}

// Define a new node if it didn't already exist in the graph.
bool define_node(std::unordered_set<std::string> &seen,
                 const std::string &name) {
  auto res = seen.insert(name);
  if (res.second) {
    std::cout << normalize(name) << " [shape=box, label=\"" << name << "\"];\n";
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {
  // Header
  std::cout << "digraph dependencies {\n";

  std::unordered_set<std::string> seen;
  std::string line;
  while (readline(std::cin, line)) {
    auto colon = line.find(':');
    if (colon == std::string::npos) {
      std::cerr << "Malformed line! Expected format: file: dep ...\n";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto file = line.substr(0, colon);
    auto nfile = normalize(file);
    define_node(seen, file);
    
    std::istringstream deps{line.substr(colon + 1)};
    for (std::string depfile; deps >> depfile; ) {
      define_node(seen, depfile);
      // Edge
      std::cout << normalize(depfile) << " -> " << nfile << ";\n";
    }
  }

  // Footer
  std::cout << "}\n";
  
  return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```sh
$ g++ -o gendot -O -Wall -Wextra gendot.cc
# Assuming bash/ksh for the extglob syntax to exclude gendot.cc.
# Or put it somewhere else.
$ g++ -MG -MM !(gendot).cc | ./gendot | dot -Tsvg -o dependencies.svg
```